# MockMvc not working for DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We Spring developers know that if one tries to delete an entity that has other associated entities, a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown.

I wrote a delete method catching both `EmptyResultDataAccessException` and `DataIntegrityViolationException` exceptions, throwing custom service-level exceptions for each case:

```
@Service
public class CityService {

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository repository;
    
    public void delete(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id); // returns 204
        }
        catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Id not found " + id); // returns 404
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Integrity violation"); // returns 400
        }
    }
}
```

I've set all up so the first scenario returns 204, the second scenario returns 404, and the third scenario returns 400. **Everything is working fine when I test it on Postman**.

However, when I try to write an integrated test using MockMvc, the `DataIntegrityViolationException` scenario doesn't work! (the other two scenarios work).

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class CityControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    (...)

    @Test
    public void deleteShouldReturnBadRequestEventWhenDependentId() throws Exception {       
        mockMvc.perform(delete("/cities/{id}", 1L))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

It's returning 204 instead of 400! I have printed some messages inside the `try` block and I have found that it is really not throwing an exception. The `try` block executes entirely, as there was no integrity violation.

```
@Service
public class CityService {

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository repository;
    
    public void delete(Long id) {
        try {
            System.out.println("START");
            repository.deleteById(id); 
            System.out.println("FINISH");
        }
        (...)
```

I am missing something about MockMvc fundamentals? Why integrity violation is being ignored when executing that MockMvc test?

I've saved a minimum-H2-just-clone-and-run project on Github:
https://github.com/acenelio/mockmvc-dataintegrity

Comment: And why should it throw an exception?  Did you use an `@MockBean` for the repository?

Comment: Because my test is trying to delete a City for which there is an associated Event entity. If I try to delete the id 1 City from Postman, DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown, but it's not thrown from the automated test. I'm not using any @MockBean because I don't want to mock anything: I want an integration test which deletes the id 1 City from the actual H2 database.

Comment: This is due to your usage of `MockMvc` and `@Transactinal` making the whole thing run in a single transaction (your test is the transactional boundary). So after issuing the delete there is nothing yet deleted. Remove `@Transactional` from your test.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot, thank you! Actually `@Transactional`, as far as I know, makes each `@Test` method to rollback database (which is the behavior I want). However, `DataIntegrityViolationException` doesn't work with `@Transacional`. So I chose to create another class without `@Transactional` (as you said) in order to test the `DataIntegrityViolationException` scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataIntegrityViolationException` does NOT work properly with `@Transactional`, even in a common service method like:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
    
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id); 
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to automate test a `DataIntegrityViolationException` scenario, you should NOT annotate your test class with `@Transactional`.

So if your writing transactional integrated tests (which rollback database for each test), you may want to create another test class without `@Transactional` annotation to test your `DataIntegrityViolationException` scenario.